# Data from back end not showing in front end using django

Tags: django

I am trying to insert data into my frontend but not sure what I did wrong here. Here is the code...

I don't have any errors showing in my terminal or web browser.

my views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_list_or_404

from adopt.models import Adopt


# Create your views here.
def adopt(request):
    return render(request, 'adopts/adopt.html')

def adopt_detail(request, id):
    single_pet = get_list_or_404(Adopt, pk=id)

    data = {
        'single_pet': single_pet,
    }
    return render(request, 'adopts/adopt_detail.html', data)


def search(request):
    adopt = Adopt.objects.order_by('-created_date')

    if 'keyword' in request.GET:
        keyword = request.GET['keyword']
        if keyword:
            adopt = adopt.filter(description__icontains=keyword)
            data = {
                'adopt': adopt,
            }
            return render(request, 'adopts/search.html', data)
```

my models.py

```
from django.db import models
from datetime import datetime
from ckeditor.fields import RichTextField

# Create your models here.
class Adopt(models.Model):

    pet_gender = (
        ('F','Female'),
        ('M', 'Male'),
    )

    state_choice = (
        ('AL', 'Alabama'),
        ('AK', 'Alaska'),
        ('AZ', 'Arizona'),
        ('AR', 'Arkansas'),
        ('CA', 'California'),
        ('CO', 'Colorado'),
        ('CT', 'Connecticut'),
        ('DE', 'Delaware'),
        ('DC', 'District Of Columbia'),
        ('FL', 'Florida'),
        ('GA', 'Georgia'),
        ('HI', 'Hawaii'),
        ('ID', 'Idaho'),
        ('IL', 'Illinois'),
        ('IN', 'Indiana'),
        ('IA', 'Iowa'),
        ('KS', 'Kansas'),
        ('KY', 'Kentucky'),
        ('LA', 'Louisiana'),
        ('ME', 'Maine'),
        ('MD', 'Maryland'),
        ('MA', 'Massachusetts'),
        ('MI', 'Michigan'),
        ('MN', 'Minnesota'),
        ('MS', 'Mississippi'),
        ('MO', 'Missouri'),
        ('MT', 'Montana'),
        ('NE', 'Nebraska'),
        ('NV', 'Nevada'),
        ('NH', 'New Hampshire'),
        ('NJ', 'New Jersey'),
        ('NM', 'New Mexico'),
        ('NY', 'New York'),
        ('NC', 'North Carolina'),
        ('ND', 'North Dakota'),
        ('OH', 'Ohio'),
        ('OK', 'Oklahoma'),
        ('OR', 'Oregon'),
        ('PA', 'Pennsylvania'),
        ('RI', 'Rhode Island'),
        ('SC', 'South Carolina'),
        ('SD', 'South Dakota'),
        ('TN', 'Tennessee'),
        ('TX', 'Texas'),
        ('UT', 'Utah'),
        ('VT', 'Vermont'),
        ('VA', 'Virginia'),
        ('WA', 'Washington'),
        ('WV', 'West Virginia'),
        ('WI', 'Wisconsin'),
        ('WY', 'Wyoming'),
    )

    year_choice = []
    for r in range(2000, (datetime.now().year+1)):
        year_choice.append((r,r))

    pet_title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    state = models.CharField(choices=state_choice, max_length=100)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    gender = models.CharField(choices=pet_gender, max_length=100, blank=True)
    breed = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    year = models.IntegerField(('year'), choices=year_choice)
    pet_photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='photots/%Y/%m/%d/')
    description = RichTextField()
    price = models.IntegerField()
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.pet_title
```

Comment: Add your templates and urls.py please.

Comment: This is my urls.py

from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.adopt, name='adopt'),
    path('<int:id>', views.adopt_detail, name='adopt_detail'),
    path('search', views.search, name='search'),
]

Comment: Okay, but the error is most likely in the templates.  Edit your question with adopt_detail.html and search.html.

Comment: I just posted my html template as an answer since i had some trouble with editing my question.

Answer (score 0):

```py
    {% extends 'base.html' %}

    {% block content %}


    <div class="Featured-container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12">
                <div class="Featured-header">
                    <h1>Featured Pets</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            {% for adopt in adopts %}
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-xl-3">
                <div class="card Featured-card Pet-card">
                    <img class=" card-img-top" src=" 
   {{adopt.pet_photo.url}}" alt="Card image cap"
                    style="min-height:262px; max-height: 262px;">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">{{adopt.pet_title}}</h5>
                        <p class="card-text">{{adopt.price}}</p>
                        <p class="card-text">{{adopt.description | safe}}</p>
                        <a href="{% url 'adopt_detail' adopt.id %}" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            {% endfor %}

        </div>
    </div>



    {% endblock %}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You are passing in `adopt` in your view, but you're referencing `adopts` in your template.  In addition, your queries have the wrong syntax.  The code below should work.

```py
def search(request):
    adopt = Adopt.objects.all().order_by('-created_date')    # CHANGE

    if 'keyword' in request.GET:
        keyword = request.GET['keyword']
        if keyword:
            adopts = Adopt.objects.filter(description__icontains=keyword).order_by('-created_date')   # CHANGE
            data = {
                'adopts': adopts,    # CHANGE
            }
            return render(request, 'adopts/search.html', data)
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast response. I just gave it a try and I still have the issue of data not showing with no errors ( 200 response in the terminal )

Comment: There were several syntax errors, after looking at it more closely.  I've edited my answer once again.  Hope this helps, @AthenaTheKatze.